# Summarize uniq count in LINUX

Tags: linux

I have file containing below detail in Linux shell

```
Sam  , apple
jhon , banana
Sam  , apple
jhon , banana
Sam  , mango
jhon , banana
jhon , apple
Sam  , apple
Sam  , papaya
```

With my Linux command i can have a result as below

```
cat /names/fav.log  | cut -d "," -f 1|sort |uniq -c | sort -rn
```

result

```
Sam     5
jhon    4
```

But i need uniq  count of second columns. as below

```
Required result
Sam     3
jhon    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's doable by only piping a list of commands, you need to loop over the first column like this:

```
for i in $(cat list.txt | cut -f 1 -d ',' | sort | uniq); do echo $i $(grep $i list.txt | cut -f 2 -d ',' | sort | uniq | wc -l); done;
```

And the output is:

```
jhon 2
Sam 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `cut -d "," -f 1` or put it in the end of the command, like this:

```
cat /names/fav.log  | sort |uniq -c | sort -rn
```

or

```
cat /names/fav.log |sort |uniq -c | sort -rn | cut -d "," -f 1
```